# Из абстрактной функции обратиться к конкретной переменной

Tags: c#

Есть два класса, первый абстрактный, второй наследуется от него
В первом есть функция, которая должна использовать поля, которые находятся во втором классе
Пример кода:

```
abstract class Class1
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a); // тут заменить a на что-то вроде a.base, только в обратную сторону
    }
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    string a = "string";
}
```

Можно как-нибудь реализовать без переопределения функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
abstract class Class1
{
    protected abstract string a { get; }
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a); 
    }
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    protected override string a { get { return "string"; } }
}
```

Comment: Я бы хотел увидеть решение для полей, но это тоже подойдёт под мой случай